# Did Jonas Salk say "I have had dreams and I have had nightmares", etc.? Where?

Tags: quotes

Yet another quote that zillions of people have repeated all over the
web, with no one giving a source. It's attributed to Jonas Salk, and the
two main variations I've found are:

> I have had dreams and I have had nightmares, but I have
> conquered my nightmares because of my dreams.

> I have had dreams and I have had nightmares. I overcame my
> nightmares because of my dreams.

Wikiquote cites *Wisdom for the Soul: Five Millennia of Prescriptions
for Spiritual Healing* by Larry Chang, and [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=-T3QhPjIxhIC&printsec=frontcover) shows the
quote on page 254. The Wikiquote version and Chang's version differ from
each other and from both the versions above.

Does anyone know whether Salk actually wrote or said some such quote,
and where? I'm not prepared to take Larry Chang's word for it when he
doesn't cite a source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Amazon (link not provided), "Wisdom for the Soul: Five Millennia of Prescriptions for Spiritual Healing by Larry Chang" is listed with the date April 28, 2006, which I assume to be the publication date. [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2228229.Wisdom_for_the_Soul) agrees with this publication date. The 2006 date agrees with the copyright of the book ([Google Books link](https://books.google.com/books?id=-T3QhPjIxhIC&printsec=frontcover)). Thus, I will assume the book was not published before January 1, 2006.

**The earliest version of the quote I could find online was in [Wikiquotes](https://en.wikiquote.org/w/index.php?title=Jonas_Salk&oldid=126904), appearing on October 27, 2005.** It appeared under the category "Attributed" and *not* "Sourced," so it probably wasn't extant earlier. I could not find any older versions of the quote even after hours of searching. The next oldest confirmed version was on October 17, 2007 [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20071017121700/http://oneliners-and-proverbs.com/engels/I3_ig-is.html) and then in April 18, 2008 [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080418041803/https://biggsuccess.com/bigg-quotes/).

A problem with this methodology is that InternetArchive isn't archiving much random webpages from earlier, so I cannot confirm when the quote first popped up at earlier times.

This appears to be one of the times where Wikipedia contains a random fact, an (untrustworthy) book uses it, and Wikipedia gets to cite it. [This](https://www.newyorker.com/tech/annals-of-technology/how-a-raccoon-became-an-aardvark) is an example of fabricated facts on Wikipedia getting published in books (and in this case, even a book published by the University of Chicago). The book states it hence

> This kind of feedback loop—wherein an error that appears on Wikipedia then trickles to sources that Wikipedia considers authoritative, which are in turn used as evidence for the original falsehood—is a documented phenomenon.

As the Wikiquote quote appeared before the book, the book likely copied Wikiquote and  Wikiquote cited it. This removes all credibility the book has. The lack of similar versions of the quote (online and in print) also makes the attribution unlikely. *Where there should be evidence, there isn't.*

> Did Jonas Salk say “I have had dreams and I have had nightmares”, etc.?

**Jonas Salk likely did not make a similar statement. The claim is dubious.**

Comment: Actually, it seems to have been added to WP on [27 Oct 2005](https://en.wikiquote.org/w/index.php?title=Jonas_Salk&oldid=126904), along with many other quotes. That quibble aside, I find your argument compelling; it’s an interesting quote and quite popular on the net, suggesting that someone would have quoted it earlier if it were real. We might add that no one on Skeptics has cited a source in nearly four years. No one has argued against this in three days, either, so I’ll accept. Thanks :)

Comment: @TomZych I agree with you. This answer is *not* satisfying. I will continue to look out for a better explanation.

Comment: @TomZych Also, thanks for catching that mistake. I know I saw the October version, but somehow cited the November version in the answer. :( The pre- and post-October versions are extremely distinctive because of the striking difference in length.

Comment: For those wondering whether citogenesis is real, it is, at least according to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_citogenesis_incidents)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Interesting! Don't recall ever finding the list before.